# TableView adding the same functions to every view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, contacts

Hey! I was wondering how I can make the tableview add the same functions (buttons, text fields etc.) to the view it adds.

This is how I was thinking.

I want it to work kinda like the contacts app.

The user clicks on an add button and Types in the name f that field in the table view. When the user taps on the text it will add a new view. And for every view it will add the exact same functions which in my case would be the buttons and the text fields.

Comment: seems you have to program each ui event and add table cells accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to program each ui event and add table cells accordingly.

You should take a look at 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

and

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do your own UITableViewCell. See the tableview programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to insert custom cells using

> `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`
>
> Inserts rows in the receiver at the locations identified by an array of index paths, with an option to animate the insertion.
> [(UITableView Reference)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *toListInTable = [listOfViews retain];
```

When you try to add new view to the table view, just add it in `toListInTable`. Then just reload the tableview like `[tableView reloadData]`;

Within the following method, just load the views from `toListInTable`

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom UITableViewCell :-)